# cellBrowser placed in composite - do I have to attach directly to the rootpanel (or rootlayoutpanel)

Tags: gwt2

when using a cellbrowser and adding that widget to a flowpanel (to be placed wherever, downstream), for some reason the end result is dead (a blank screen)...vs if I add directly to the rootpanel (or layout panel)

Answer (score 1):

Also had the same problem. I had to use a `<g:HTMLPanel>` as the parent of the `CellBrowser` (as seen in the GWT Showcase).

Answer (score 0):

Do you have some sample code that will reproduce this?

Answer (score 0):

below is the code for the composite...essentially, what I'd like to do is in another class, attached this composite to a flowpanel and do whatever with it...but, the reality is, I have to attach is directly to the RootPanel (or RootLayoutPanel)...any other abstraction causes it to bail

for example

```
FlowPanel fp = new FlowPanel();
V2_M76Rolodex v = new V2_M76Rolodex();

fp.add(v); // not going to work

RootPanel.get.add(v) works


public class V2_M76Rolodex extends Composite {

/*
a bunch of code here for getting data and 
populating the tree - works, not at issue or relevant
*/

 public V2_M76Rolodex() {
       TreeViewModel model = new CustomTreeModel();
       CellBrowser browser = new CellBrowser(model, null);
       browser.setKeyboardSelectionPolicy(KeyboardSelectionPolicy.ENABLED);
       browser.addStyleName("rolodex_cell_browser");
       initWidget(browser);
 }

}
```